# Purpose of 'options' in Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Having a bit of trouble getting a Third-Party Cloud Code module up and running on Parse.

I'm following along with Parse.com's 'Integrating with Third-Party Services' guide and seem to have run into a brick wall.

Here's my main.js:

```
var echonest = require('cloud/echonest');

echonest.initialize('MyAPIKey');

// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response) {
  response.success('Hello world!');
});

Parse.Cloud.define("create", function(request, response) {
    echonest.create(
        {
            type: "song",
            name: request.params.name
        }
    ).then(function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success(httpResponse);
    }, function(httpResponse) {
        console.error(httpResponse);
        response.error('create failed');
    });
});
```

which speaks to echonest.js:

```
(function() {

    var url = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/';
    var key = '';

    module.exports = {
        initialize: function(apiKey) {
            key = apiKey;
            return this;
        },
        create: function(params, options) {
            requestBody = params;
            requestBody.api_key = key;
            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + 'tasteprofile/create',
                body: requestBody,
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                if (options && options.success) {
                    options.success(httpResponse);
                } else {
                    console.error('(success) options not found');
                    console.error(httpResponse);
                }
            }, function(httpResponse) {
                if (options && options.error) {
                    options.error(httpResponse);
                } else {
                    console.error('(error) options not found');
                    console.error(httpResponse);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

I'm getting success messages back from the echonest API, but they fail in echonest.js due to options and/or options.success not being defined.